# Unbounded derived Nakayama lemma

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, derived-categories, local-rings

Let $R$ be a (commutative) local ring, which I don't assume to be noetherian. Let $m$ be its maximal ideal, and $k$ its residue field.

> Let $X$ be a complex of $R$-modules with finitely generated homology groups.  Suppose that $X\otimes^L_R k = 0$. Is $X$ acyclic ?

The statement holds if $X$ is bounded below - this follows from the ordinary Nakayama lemma and the fact that if $X$ is nonnegatively graded, $H_0(X\otimes^L_R k)\cong H_0(X)\otimes_R k$.

The statement also holds more generally if $m$ is finitely generated - this was pointed out to me by Zhouhang Mao, the argument is as follows: for any $f$ in $m$, the cofiber of $f : R\to R$, $R/f$ is a finite extension of $R/(f)$-modules ($R/(f)$ is the ordinary quotient), so if $X\otimes^L_R R/(f) = 0$, $X\otimes_R^L R/f$ must also vanish and so $f$ must be an equivalence on $X$, i.e. for all $n$, $f: H_n(X)\to H_n(X)$ is an isomorphism.

This implies (by the ordinary Nakayama lemma) that $H_n(X) = 0$ for all $n$.  A similar argument with induction shows that if $X\otimes^L_R R/(f_1,...,f_n) = 0$ with $f_1,...,f_n \in m$, then $X=0$. Finite generation of $m$ proves the claim (in particular, this deals with the case where $R$ is noetherian)

One can also see that the claim holds if $m$ is nilpotent : The argument is by induction and using the short exact sequence $0\to m^n/m^{n+1}\to R/m^{n+1}\to R/m^n\to 0$ ($m^n/m^{n+1}$ is a module over $k$)

> What about when $m$ is not finitely generated or nilpotent ?

I'm not sure how to make sense of "derived $m$-completeness" for $m$ non finitely generated, but certainly if one can make sense of such a thing it should hold for $X$ "derived $m$-complete".

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331487/derived-nakayama-for-complete-modules) seems related but assumes $I$ is finitely generated (see in particular the edited part of the accepted answer)

Comment: Could you clarify what $X \otimes^{L} k$ means for an unbounded complex of $R$ modules? I get worried about examples like the complex $\dots \to^{x} k[x] \to^x k[x] \to^x  \dots$.

Comment: @user1092847 : that's a good question, that example also came up when I was thinking about it. Here's at least a point of view : the derived $\infty$-category is the presentable stabilization of the connective derived $\infty$-category and as such it acquires a unique (homotopy) colimit preserving tensor structure, and that is the one I want.

Comment: Let me check: this derived tensor product should correspond to the classical one (maybe due to Spaltenstein?), i.e. pick a K-flat resolution and take the tensor product of complexes? The free complex mentioned above might not be K-flat or K-projective, but I don't know how to check that (I only learned the abstract theory).

Comment: Yes @Z.M it is the classical one, both are essentially defined as derived functors. The complex $C$ above isn't $K$-flat because if it were then we would have $C \otimes k = C \otimes^L k \cong 0 \otimes^L k = 0$, but $C \otimes k$ is not an acyclic complex ($k = k[x]/(x)$).